# Compilation error when building gnu-screen package for Freescale P2020 Board

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen, make, cross-compilation

I am trying to run screen package on a Freescale P2020RDB Hardware board. I have successfully run `./configure` and `make` and `make install` commands for the package I get the following log error:

**No more PTYs. Sorry, could not find a PTY. [screen is terminating].**

It doesn't work correctly on this Freescale board as it does in a normal Ubuntu system when installed through apt-get command.

Kindly help me how can we successfully run screen package on this Freescale P2020 Board with a Customized Linux kernel running on it.

Comment: Do you have `tic` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the ./configure script is missing identifying whether or not you have the "tic" entry-description compiler. Assuming that it is indeed missing on the machine, you should install it and run the build again. You did not tell on which distro you are trying this. If it is Fedora, you should install "tic" by "dnf install -y ncurses" (or "yum install -y ncurses" on earlier Fedora distros). You can also download the ncurses sources and build, and then run your build again.

Rami Rosen

Comment: I am trying to run the screen package for a Customized Linux on Freescale P2020 Board. By cross compiling ncurses library tic error is resolved but screen doesn't work correctly as it does in a normal Ubuntu system when installed through apt-get command. It shows      No more PTYs.
Sorry, could not find a PTY.
[screen is terminating].